# RegEx to remove punctuation if it is adjacent to letter

Tags: java, regex, text

I'm working on a Java project and I want to use a RegEx to replace punctuation, specifically only commas and full-stops, that are adjacent to a letter (except o or O). For example in a string like `Love. , o.o` I only want to remove the full-stop after the word Love and leave the rest (New string: `Love , o.o`).
I tried `[A-NP-Za-np-z][.,]`, but obviously this removes the last letter of the word as well (New string: `Lov , o.o`). Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Does this give you the functonality you want? https://regex101.com/r/bD5iX2/1

Comment: @IanGabes No, since it replaces . and , even if they are adjacent to an o. Also, it still removes the last letter before the punctuation I think.

Comment: So `o.o` should not match the regex because it is followed by the o? Also, I am using a non-capturing group, so it is not matching the last letter :)

Comment: ο.ο should not match because there's an 'o' before the . 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=[A-NP-Za-np-z])[.,]
```

`(?<=[A-NP-Za-np-z])` will assert if previous character is one of those defined inside `[...]`.

In Java:

```
txt = txt.replace("(?<=[A-NP-Za-np-z])[.,]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like this! :) I'll accept the answer in 3'.

Comment: Just an additional demo link on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gR2yM5/1). The example uses inline modifiers as well.